# Text colors in asp.net core/razor views bland

Tags: resharper, resharper-2016

The text coloring on my asp.net core projects seem to default to just two or three colors - relatively bland. I've looked through all the Resharper settings but can't identify anything out of the ordinary. I just did a default installation of Resharper and still can't get all the colorful highlighting that i have seen on sample videos on youtube etc. What could be the difference?

Here is my asp.net core project:

[image: current asp.net core project]

This is a screenshot of youtube video of someone elses Resharper text highlighting - seems much more colorful!

[image: colorful text]

I have Resharper 2016.3 installed running on Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Resharper`->`Options...`->`Code Inspection`->`Settings` and make sure `Enable code analysis` and `Color identifiers` are selected.

[image]